# How to get() values from spreadsheet in columns instead of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I am using Python 3 and have been trying to retrieve values from a google spreadsheet in columns instead of rows. I have read the sample [here that explains that majorDimension need to be changed to COLUMNS](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)
However, this code:

```
rangeName = 'sheet1!A2:D4?majorDimension=COLUMNS'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
   
values = result.get('values', [])
    print (values)
```

Returns

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/143FCe6qayfm-g8-PvYr_rz5fF4Fjpg-ZZVWbF11xF6o/values/HCMasterX%21A2%3AD4%2CmajorDimension%3DCOLUMNS?alt=json returned "Unable to parse range: HCMasterX!A2:D4,majorDimension=COLUMNS">
```

Meanwhile,

```
rangeName = 'sheet1!A2:D4'
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
```

Works perfectly fine and prints out the correct values.
I have tried changing rangeName to many other variations such as ending it with
",majorDimensions=COLUMNS" but none of them have worked.
Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just pass it as a paramater to get:

```
rangeName = 'sheet1!A2:D4'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, 
    range=rangeName, 
    majorDimension='COLUMNS').execute()
```